# How to represent the statement mathematically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am practicing mathematical approaches.

I got all good, except this one:

The excess of $a$ over $b$ is $n$ units

I think that *excess* mean $+$, so $b + a$ = n, because is $a$ **over** $b$ is equal to $n$.

Although in this case, it does not matter, since it is a sum.

So, my result was:

$b + a = n$

I also thought of it as:

"The units that make $ a $ greater than $ b $ are $ n $", then:

a + n = b

**But the correct result is: $a - b = n$**

But, this is not close either, since this result is: $ a - b = -n $.

I think my mistake is in the meaning of "exceeds"

Comment: This seems more related to English than mathematics if you ask me. I understand "excess of $a$ over $b$ as "$a$ is larger than $b$ by $n$." So $a=b+n$.

Comment: The mistake is you'd never say that. I would personally take "a over b" to mean a/b. Then, what's the excess of it? Meaningless the way that is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The excess of $a$ over $b$ is $n$ units" means "$a$ is greater than $b$ by $n$ units", so $a=b+n$.

Comment: Many thanks Rócherz

Comment: You are very welcome, Mattiu. :)

Comment: "The excess of $a$ over $b$" is just bad English and I wouldn't try to assign it a meaning. In good idiomatic English, you would say "$a$ exceeds $b$ by $n$".